# Regex - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code:

```
var patt = new RegExp("/.+/g");
var device_id = patt.exec("javascript:project_id:256, device_id:2232");
```

However device_id seems to be blank after executing the above code and I can't work out why.

I am actually trying to get the device id (2232) however used the above pattern for testing as I thought this should return everything, below is the regex I tried to use for the device id.

```
/device_id:([0-9]+)/
```

I have also tried using the javascript.match and that was also not solving the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the regex delimiters in `RegExp` constructor is double quotes then you don't need to include the forward slash delimiter within the double quotes. And also, the modifiers in our case `g` (*global modifier*) must be as a separate parameter.

```
> var patt = new RegExp("device_id:([0-9]+)", "g");
undefined
> patt.exec("javascript:project_id:256, device_id:2232")[1]
'2232'
```

**OR**

```
> var patt = /device_id:([0-9]+)/g;
undefined
> patt.exec("javascript:project_id:256, device_id:2232")[1]
'2232'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try instantiating your RegEx as

```
var patt = new RegExp(".+");
```

or

```
var patt = /.+/g;
```

Comment: Well, he was wondering why it was null, and mentioned that he was just using that one for testing.